# Advanced search redirecting to another page then filter further

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, search

I'm trying to do an advanced search that allows the user to select custom post taxonomies along with a typing field for another taxonomy.

I've gotten it to go through to the page I want with the details in the URL, however the results don't appear, I've tried a loop and variety of tutorials but no luck.

To make the challenge more fun, I'm hoping to have extra filters on that page to allow the user to narrow down their search without losing the original data.

Is this even possible? If so can anyone assist please or point me in the right direction.

I'm new to custom post taxonomies and advanced search so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use manual sql queries to fetch the records as per your customized requirement and filters rather than the query function. Otherwise install a plugin that creates advanced search form with filters.

I am also sharing a reference link below which might be useful for you:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-search-form-in-wordpress-for-custom-post-types/

If none of it helps, do mention the output you are getting with your code.